# Month,Year in beween two dates when one date is null

Tags: mysql

I have a table for designation for all employees.In that whenever role get changed,new entry will be there.Like

> 'Sr. Engg'- start date 2013-04-01 and end date 2016-03-31

Now the same guy get promoted to

> 'Lead Engg' -start date 2016-04-01 and end date'0000-00-00'

because I dont know the end date for this present role.

I'm using this table for showing it in Payslip. So when he want the payslip for `March 2016`,then his payslip should show his role as `Sr Engg` When he want for `Apr 2016`, then the role should be 'Lead Engg'.

For im using one query,but it does not work.

```
id  empid   role        startdate   enddate
1   1     Sr Engineer   2013-04-01  2016-03-31
3   2     Asst.Manager  2013-04-01  2016-03-31
2   1     Lead Engg     2016-04-01  0000-00-00
4   2     Manager       2016-04-01  0000-00-00

SELECT * FROM ROLE 
WHERE EMPLOYEE = 1 
    AND ('2016-03' between DATE_FORMAT(STARTDATE,"%Y-%m") AND DATE_FORMAT(ENDDATE,"%Y-%m"));
```

it return record for `employee = 1`, `mar 2016`, but for the same employee `apr 2016`, it doesnt return anything.

Create Statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `role` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `employee` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `role` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `startdate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `enddate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `Fk_role_employee_idx` (`employee`),
  CONSTRAINT `Fk_role_employee` FOREIGN KEY (`employee`) REFERENCES `employee` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO `simpayroll`.`role`
(`id`,
`employee`,
`role`,
`startdate`,
`enddate`)
VALUES
(<{id: }>,
<{employee: }>,
<{role: }>,
<{startdate: }>,
<{enddate: }>);
```

Comment: Wouldn't an unknown end date simply be NULL? In which case, you could use COALESCE(enddate,CURDATE()).

Comment: i set default value as null, but still when i leave that it shows error while inserting. So i used '0000-00-00'

Comment: What error does it show?

Comment: Incorrect date value: 'NULL' for column 'enddate' at row 1

Comment: Can we see the insert statement, and the CREATE table statement?

Comment: i added that in my question.

Comment: That's not the insert statement. We need to see what that looks like post preparation

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use a query like this:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  ROLE
WHERE
  EMPLOYEE = 1 AND (
    STARTDATE>='2016-03-01'
    AND (ENDDATE<=LAST_DAY('2016-03-01') OR ENDDATE='0000-00-00')
  );
```

I know here we are repeating the same date (the first day of the month) twice, but this will be the most performant as we are comparing dates with dates without string conversion, and can take advantage of an index, if present.

If an ENDDATE is null instead of 0000-00-00, which is more preferable, you can just modifiy it to:

```
    ....
    AND (ENDDATE<=LAST_DAY('2016-03-01') OR ENDDATE IS NULL)
```

Comment: From your query, it returns row id 2, but for mar 2016 it should return row id 1. Because, user will select Month and Year, with this data i have to search in database.

Comment: @anu the user will select month and year, but what you need is the first day of the month which is always 1, i would suggest you to use this approach